# How To Clear Interval After Function Done with Its Work

Tags: javascript

I am building a countdown timer. If the timer is over it stops the clock at zero and prints 'done' on in the console.

My issue is, when the clock reaches zero it should print 'done' only once and `setInterval` should be cleared.

```js
const endDate = new Date(Date.now() + 15000); // 15 seconds from now
document.getElementById('end').textContent = endDate.toISOString();

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input")
console.log(new Date(endDate))
const clock = () => {
  const end = new Date(endDate)
  const now = new Date()
  const diff = (end - now) / 1000

  if (diff < 0) {
    console.log("Done")
    return;
  }

  // COnvert In days
  inputs[0].value = (Math.floor(diff / 3600 / 24))
  inputs[1].value = (Math.floor((diff / 3600) % 24))
  inputs[2].value = (Math.floor(diff / 60 % 60))
  inputs[3].value = (Math.floor(diff % 60))
}

clock();

const clearInt = setInterval(() => {
  clock()
}, 1000);

if (clock === 0) {
  clearInterval(clearInt);
}
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<span id="end"></span><br/>
<input /><input /><input /><input />
```

Comment: Call `clearInterval(clearInt)` ***within*** the `if (diff < 0)` block, as that's the code that gets executed when the timer ends. `clock` doesn't return anything so comparing it to an integer will never work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I add `clearInterval(clearInt)` inside `if block`, says `cannot access 'clearInt' before initialization
    at clock`

Comment: why does it say `clock === 0`? `clock` is the name of a function

Comment: @RahulSharma then you didn't follow what I said properly, as it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5z7gbf8u/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this code is working fine, but it seems to be working only if count down timer is running, if timer is over and then you visit page, then it is throwing error [https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsharma49/3jwqscru/](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsharma49/3jwqscru/)

Comment: `if timer is over` - the timer is set to now + 15 seconds when the page loads.  How can it be over?

Comment: @James I've updated the question so the timer always end 15 seconds from now when you start the snippet. This makes the question more usable for those visiting in the future. Since otherwise they wouldn't be able to see the initial countdown. This keeps the original spirit of the question intact but invalidates the comment "if timer is over and then you visit page".

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code is that the check to clear the interval (`if (clock === 0)`) is outside of your `clock` function and it's only executed once, right after `setInterval` is set. Also, the condition `clock === 0` is incorrect because `clock` **is a function**, **not a number**.

To fix this, you should move the `clearInterval` logic inside your `clock` function and check the condition when `diff` is less than or equal to 0.

Example:

```js
const endDate = document.getElementById('end').innerText;
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

let clearInt; // Declare the interval variable outside the function

const clock = () => {
  const end = new Date(endDate);
  const now = new Date();
  const diff = (end - now) / 1000;

  if (diff <= 0) {
    console.log("Done");
    clearInterval(clearInt); // Clear the interval here
    return;
  }

  // Convert In days
  inputs[0].value = Math.floor(diff / 3600 / 24);
  inputs[1].value = Math.floor((diff / 3600) % 24);
  inputs[2].value = Math.floor(diff / 60 % 60);
  inputs[3].value = Math.floor(diff % 60);
};

clearInt = setInterval(clock, 1000); // Assign the interval to the variable
```

Comment: Will it work if timer is over, it might throw error if page is loaded after timer is over

Comment: @RahulSharma This answer does not suffer from the same error you encounter in your [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsharma49/3jwqscru/) (in [this comment](/q/77727589#comment137030920_77727589)). `clearInt` is declared before you access it so this shouldn't yield a ReferenceError.